Soviet cartoon about quarrel of two at a bus-stop
I remember the following episode:
Two potential passengers start a quarrel at a bus stop. The reason was quite insignificant (like the one unintentionally prevented the other to get into overfilled bus), but the quarrel turned out to be long (causing them to miss several more buses) and dramatic. Their dialogue IIRC wasn't voiced with real speech — but instead its "plot" was visualized (i.e. if one says "you're a donkey (or something else)", other visually turns into that). The episode ends with both of them turned into dirt puddles, with final spittle flying from the one of them to the other during the departure of the last bus.
The graphics were quite simplistic (I don't remember whether it was color or BW).
The episode was quite short.
I don't remember whether it was an independent short cartoon, or within a sequence of (plot-independent) shorts composed into one full-time cartoon (for example, agitating for culture of behavior) — but it certainly was not a part of a full cartoon with single plot.
Country: Soviet Union (less probably — one of ex-USSR countries soon after its collapse).
Time: no info, probably 1950x-1980x (less probably — 1990x).

Sounds like it might be Polish cartoon series Bolek and Lolek. But I don't remember seeing the bus stop episode. I do remember that Bolek and Lolek did not have any dialogue.

@Vekzhivi, thanks, I don't think so. I've just looked for pictures of Bolek and Lolek — the graphics were different. Although I don't remember the style of graphic of the movie in question, I am sure that characters didn't look so child-like and pretty (most probable it was sarcastic/caricature style).

Could it be Gustav (Hungarian Gusztáv), 1961-1977 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_(film_series)
Gustav, also known as Gustavus, (Hungarian Gusztáv, 1961-1977) was Hungarian series of animated short cartoons (5 minutes) for adults. It was extremely popular in Eastern Europe, where it has achieved cult status.
Each episode tells an adventure of the main character, Gustav, related to the gray realities of urban life. Characteristic feature of the show was that episodes were independent: for example, Gustav is sometimes a bachelor, sometimes has large family. In Eastern Europe and Yugoslavia the episodes were broadcast on TV in the 80s, usually as airtime filler. The series was also broadcast in Western Europe and even in New Zealand - because it was not using language, other than gibberish sound, it was able to easily transcend boundaries. In 2013 and 2014, Gusztáv was again broadcast in Croatia, on national television, usually as an airtime filler. However, over 40 episodes were broadcast between films in special Christmas/New Year film marathons.[1]
Example of the style and episode that seems a bit like what you described:




Well, thanks for your suggestion. It may appear one of episodes of Gusztáv. But the episode you've attached has nothing similar to what I remembered.

One guy here suggested that it is one of cartoons of Kyivnaukfilm — but info he provided can't be verified (either that cartoon is lost or at least not present over the Internet, or that guy mistaken — I don't know).

Yeah, there are like 120 7-minutes long Gustav episodes. Some are more... fantastical... than the rest. For example, that zebra imagine spot in this episode, in some episodes it is nothing but imagine spots.
